# Symfony2 on Google App Engine - Deployments limit

Tags: google-app-engine, symfony

I'm trying to deploy my SF2 app on GAE, but I have reached the limit for the uploaded files.

`Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Max number of files and blobs is 10000.
--- end server output ---`

I have googled a lot, but still don't know what to do with that. Does anybody know how to increase this limit or what to do in this case?

Comment: [Only when nothing (!) else works you should consider zip packages](https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#zip-packages)

Comment: how do you deploy your app? Are you follow the google guidelines as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world)?

Comment: Yep, I follow this guideline. But my app is bigger than just "hello world" :) and after installing all composer dependencies it's about 15k files.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a [hard limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments), and definitely a problem. I think a Symfony Standard app with all the vendors and a warmed-up cache is going to be over 10,000 files.

I think "what to do" is to not use GAE for Symfony projects.

Comment: Do you know is it possible to increase this limit somehow, for example, by contacting the google or buying some platinum packages or whatever :)

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to research it.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload more than 10k files if you use Git in your GAE project:

https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-setup

**WARNING: This way is not free**